# java refer to component by a variable name

Tags: java, jcombobox

okay, i'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do the following:

say i have:

```
jcombobox someCombo1 = new jcombobox();
jcombobox someCombo2 = new jcombobox();

changeSomething(someCombo1);
changeSomething(someCombo2);
```

i want to be able to refer to this combobox later, but by a variable from a method, say:

```
public void changeSomething(jcombobox inCombo){
      inCombo.addItem("something")
}
```

so, that when the "something" item is added, it's added to the someCombo1, someCombo2 comboboxes, is this in any way possible?

am i looking at it wrong? haha

i have some code that manipulates A LOT of comboboxes with a long method body, each time, i want to condense it

Comment: *'when the "something" item is added, it's added to the someCombo1, someCombo2 comboboxes'* That's what your code does so the question doesn't make a whole lot of sense to us.

Comment: yeah i just realized this....i'm a dumbass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like,

```
public static void changeSomething(JComboBox<String> inCombo){
      inCombo.addItem("something");
}
```

**Note** that it is [`JComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html). Since your method doesn't depend on any instance fields I would make it `static` and you should not use [`raw-types`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).